# Twitter Special Characters and Emoticons UTF-8 JSON parsing

Tags: json, node.js, twitter, utf-8, couchdb

I am connecting to the Twitter Stream through a Node.js (Javascript) server, parsing Tweets, and then storing them in a CouchDB instance.  The issue is when I try and write to CouchDB I get this error about 40% of the time:

```
{ error: 'bad_request', reason: 'invalid UTF-8 JSON' }
```

When I compare the Tweets that are stored successfully and the ones that are not, it seems like the difference is the existence of special characters in the Tweet or user description.  Emoticons (hearts, smiley faces, etc.), Asian language characters, etc.

How can I correctly parse and store these Tweets in CouchDB?  I think its a CouchDB issue since when I log the data to my console using Node.js I see the Emoticons.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the issue was with the setting of Content-Length in node.js when sending the PUT request.  I was calculating the length of the string prior to encoding and therefore when Node expanded the UTF8 special characters, they took up more space.

Lesson learned:  Be careful when calculating the length of a JSON object, especially with special characters.